# remove numeric xml tag using java

Tags: java, regex, xml

I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>
<1>
<TITLE>A Sample Article</TITLE>
<SECT>The First Major Section      <PARA>This section will introduce a subsection.</PARA>
    <2>
    <SECT>The Subsection Heading         <PARA>This is the text of the subsection.         </PARA>      
    </SECT>
</SECT>
</ARTICLE>
```

I want to remove the numeric tags "<1>" and "<2>" using Java.

Parsers won't work as its an invalid xml. I need another solution such as a regular expression or any other idea.

Comment: is the `1` of `<1>` variable, or always a literal `1`?

Comment: @Bohemian there's a `<2>` in there as well.  It's not entirely clear what's been tried and what the problem with it was though.

Comment: That worked fine .  Was wondering if we need to replace the the Tags <1> and <2>  to <_1>  and <_2>  respectively and so what would be the regular expression .  Am a newbie at regular expression and would appreciate any pointers. Thanks

Comment: *Parsers won't work as its an invalid xml.* I doubt much research went into that. If parsers wouldn't work with invalid xml, there wouldn't be parsed much and most websites would show blank pages, as there's a whole lot of crap xml out there and this xml isn't *that* bad.  :P  I have not tried it with this particular data. But I see no reason why e.g. a simple SAXReader would trip on this.  You don't make the handler do anything with the stuff you don't want and that's it.  SAX won't mind the missing `<ARTICLE>` header either and if you really need it for something you could probably fake it.

Comment: @Arjan  I Tried the SAXReader   and i got the following error 'Exception in thread "main" org.apache.commons.jxpath.JXPathException: Dom4J parser error; Error on line 1 of document  : The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed. Nested exception: The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.
 at test.pkg.RegExp.parseXML(RegExp.java:71)
 at test.pkg.RegExp.main(RegExp.java:56) '

Comment: There aren't any numeric tags in your XML. They aren't tags, and it isn't XML. So there's no point treating it as XML or looking for a tag. You need to look for a character string in a non-XML file, as the answer from @Piazza demonstrates.

Comment: @Arjan You're thinking of HTML, where the policy of "be liberal in what you accept" has led to a culture of "be careless in what you produce". The XML world is quite different. If you generate bad XML, it's useless to nearly everyone.

Comment: Ah that explains, sorry!  Also confusing, I actually meant a simple `SAXParser` and its handler. I've used it with malformed xml in much worse condition and it worked very well.  But it just needed to read key/value pairs, not any documents or XPaths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the `replaceAll` method.

```
String str = "YOUR XML HERE";
str = str.replaceAll("<[12]>", "");
```

**[IDEOne demo](https://ideone.com/8TOxkk)**

Or as **[Boheamian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256196/bohemian)** pointed in his comment you can use the `\d` shortcut for digits:

```
str = str.replaceAll("<\\d>", "");
```

Btw, if you have more than `<1>` and `<2>`, like `<n>` being `n` whatever number, then you could use:

```
str = str.replaceAll("<\\d+>", "");
```

Comment: or even `replaceAll("<\\d>", "")`

Comment: @Bohemian well, I put the character class `[12]` since OP said 1 and 2 but definitely. I've updated the answer with your comment

Comment: Thanks a lot , i modified the code to replace the occurrence of any invalid numeric tag such as <number>  to a valid tag <_number/>  using the following regex  'str = str.replaceAll("(<)(\\d+)(>)", "$1_$2/$3");'